# Why the the arithmetic of python always return 10 for this function?

Tags: python, math, numeric, numerical-methods, pointer-arithmetic

The output for this code is always 10. AM I doing something wrong? I also want assistance the negative rational exponent equation for "Vc"

**let R=10000, C=1e-6, and Vs=10**

```
   R= 10000
   C= 10**-6
   Vs= 10
   T= float(R*C)
   t= float(input("Enter the value of t:"))
   Vc=Vs*(1-(10**-(t/T)))
   print(format(Vc,".5f"))
```

Thank you in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't always get `10`.  For small numbers, you get a value other than `10`.  Try entering `.0001`, for example.

For larger values of `t`, the expression `10**-(t/T)` is so small a number that Python treats it as `0`.  So you have `10*(1-0)`, or `10`, for large enough values of `t`.  `1` is too large, so you do get `10` for an entry of `1`, and anything bigger than that. `-1`, btw, gives an interesting answer, and entering a large negative value crashes the program with an overflow error.

Answer (score 0):

Well, When your `t` is greater than 1 it will print always 10. Because `T` is `0.01` and if you provide `t` is greater than 1, your code is negotiating `1-(10**-(t/T))` to 1.

- Let's `t=1` then `t/T=100` and `10**-100=0` so `Vs*(1-0)=10`
- If you increase your `t=1` to another big integer it will always 10.

If you take `t` as much as possible a tiny number then you will see an output change.

I assume t as `0.00001234`. Now your output is `0.02837357076786451`. SO, you should take t as a minimum value to change output 10.